# No error handlers are registered, logging exception

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()                                                      

# In[2]:telegram_bot
import telegram                        
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters, Updater                     

# Bot Id:Hash, Updater
TelegramToken=''
updater = Updater(token=TelegramToken, use_context=True) 
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher         

# 상호 번역 언어  
lang_type=['ko','en','es','vi','tr']

# 텔레그램 메시지 답장
def handler(update, context):
    # 채널에서 사용하는 경우
    try:
        # 수신한 메세지와 발신 채널 id 확인
        user_text = update.channel_post.text                                      
        user_id=update.channel_post.chat.id
    
    # 그룹에서 사용하는 경우
    except:    
        # 수신한 메세지와 발신 그룹 id 확인
        user_text=update.message.text
        user_id=update.message.chat.id

    # 수신한 메세지의 언어 확인, 상호 번역후 메세지 전송
    text_src = translator.translate(user_text).src
    if text_src==lang_type[0]: 
        a = 'ko : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[0]).text + '\n' + 'en : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[1]).text + '\n' + 'es : ' +translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[2]).text + '\n' + 'vi : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[3]).text + '\n' + 'tr : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[4]).text
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id, reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id, text=a) 
    

    elif text_src==lang_type[1]:
        b = 'en : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[1]).text + '\n' + 'ko : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[0]).text + '\n' + 'es : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[2]).text + '\n' + 'vi : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[3]).text + '\n' + 'tr : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[4]).text
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id, reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id, text=b)
    

    elif text_src==lang_type[2]: 
        c = 'es : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[2]).text + '\n' + 'ko : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[0]).text + '\n' + 'en : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[1]).text + '\n' + 'vi : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[3]).text + '\n' + 'tr : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[4]).text
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id, reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id, text=c)
    

    elif text_src==lang_type[3]: 
        d = 'vi : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[3]).text + '\n' + 'ko : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[0]).text + '\n' + 'en : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[1]).text + '\n' + 'es : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[2]).text + '\n' + 'tr : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[4]).text
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id, reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id, text=d)
    

    elif text_src==lang_type[4]: 
        e = 'tr : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[4]).text + '\n' + 'ko : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[0]).text + '\n' + 'en : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[1]).text + '\n' + 'es : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[2]).text + '\n' + 'vi : ' + translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[3]).text
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id, reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id, text=e)
    

# new_message handler
echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)

# telegram.ext Updater_polling
updater.start_polling()
# %%
```

I found this works in my pc, but it creates error when I start the same code in another pc. It's like:

> No error handlers are registered, logging exception. Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/home/jh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py",
> line 646, in _network_loop_retry
> if not action_cb():   File "/home/jh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py",
> line 597, in polling_action_cb
> updates = self.bot.get_updates(   File "/home/jh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/extbot.py",
> line 222, in get_updates
> updates = super().get_updates(   File "/home/jh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line
> 130, in decorator
> result = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/jh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line
> 2945, in get_updates
> self._post(   File "/home/jh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line
> 295, in _post
> return self.request.post(   File "/home/jh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py",
> line 361, in post
> result = self._request_wrapper(   File "/home/jh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py",
> line 283, in _request_wrapper

I checked the version of python-telegram-bot on both pc and they're the same as 13.9.

I think it's the problem of the matching version but I don't know which one I should match.

can you please give any hints?

cheers

Comment: Is it the same version of python on both pc ?

Comment: Are you using Python environments in any of the PCs or are you trusting the system's Python installation? I suggest you run this inside different environments in your pc to check whether a dependency version is the problem or not